# Regex to verify content between HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby, regex, html-parsing

I'm struggling to come up with a RegEx will confirm that some text exists between two tags.  Specifically, I want to ensure that that the text "TOTAL" and "$19.00" can be found within the same table row.

I'm not planing to nest tables, so I'm not worried about a nested match, but I do want to make sure that my text is within the SAME `tr`

#### My HTML:

```
<tr style='text-align:right;'>
  <td>shipping:</td>
  <td style='padding-left:3em;'>$17.00</td>
</tr>
<tr style='text-align:right;'>
  <td>TOTAL:</td>
  <td style='padding-left:3em;'>$19.00</td>
</tr>
```

#### Regular Expression I tried:

```
/<tr\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/tr>/m
```

It's close, the second capture group has my content.  What do I need to change so only the second capture group is matched?

You can play with it on Rubular [here](http://rubular.com/r/w5RZb4pl5b)

Comment: Do not use Regex on HTML. Please use a decent parser instead. `Nokogiri` can parse fragments of HTML.

Comment: This code is part of a view test, so I think it's OK in this case.  See my comment to @Mu_is_too_short.

Comment: Hmm.. makes sense to use in that case, though it'd make the test-cases brittle. In any case, thats not the point here, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr.*?>\s*?<td.*?>TOTAL:<\/td>\s*?<td.*?>\$19\.00<\/td>\s*?<\/tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm looking to do.  I want the regex to match ONLY if TOTAL and $19.00 are present in the same `tr`.  In your solution if I change $19.00 to $20.00 it still matches.

Comment: I like it a little better as: `/<tr\b[^>]*>\s*?<td\b[^>]*>TOTAL:<\/td>\s*?<td\b[^>]*>\$19\.00<\/td>\s*?<\/tr>/`  But your answer works too.  Thanks!  (rubular link: http://rubular.com/r/6DsLINIZ1C)

Answer (score 2):

I think an HTML parser and a bit of XPath would be a better call than a regex. Something like this:

```
shipping = '//td[normalize-space(text())="shipping:"]/following-sibling::td[normalize-space(text())]'
total    = '//td[normalize-space(text())="TOTAL:"]/following-sibling::td[normalize-space(text())]'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<HTML
  <tr style='text-align:right;'>
    <td>  shipping:    </td>
    <td style='padding-left:3em;'>$17.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='text-align:right;'>
    <td>TOTAL:</td>
    <td style='padding-left:3em;'>$19.00</td>
  </tr>
HTML
has_shipping = doc.xpath(shipping).count == 1 # true
has_total    = doc.xpath(total   ).count == 1 # true
```

But without the `$17.00` and `$19.00`:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<HTML
  <tr style='text-align:right;'>
    <td>  shipping:    </td>
    <td style='padding-left:3em;'>    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='text-align:right;'>
    <td>TOTAL:</td>
    <td style='padding-left:3em;'></td>
  </tr>
HTML
has_shipping = doc.xpath(shipping).count == 1 # false
has_total    = doc.xpath(total   ).count == 1 # false
```

If you want to verify the format of the price as well then you can find just the `<td>`s you want and apply whatever Enumerable methods make sense in your situation:

```
shipping = '//td[normalize-space(text())="shipping:"]/following-sibling::td'
good_one = doc.xpath(shipping).count { |n| n.content =~ /\A\s*\$\d+\.\d{2}\s*\z/ } == 1
```

Comment: I'm using it as part of a view test. I.E:  `  it "has the total paid" {@email.should have_body_text(/regex/}`  So generally I agree with you, but in this case I think It's OK.

Comment: @SooDesuNe: It will be okay until it breaks :) I like my tests to be quite strict and unforgiving.